# newRequestQueue Android's Volley crashes

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use **Volley** to capture the server response when a GET/POST request is made to a specific URL.

For this purpose I tried to use the example code from [the Android Developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html):

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

However, the app terminates when I specify my server's URL in the variable

```
String url ="http://www.google.com";
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE:** This is the logcat:

```
[ 09-24 07:49:55.360 26661:26661 D/]HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7a6c690, tid 26661
09-24 07:49:55.410 26661-26661/test.com.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-24 07:49:55.480 26661-26661/test.com.test D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-24 07:49:55.480 26661-26661/test.com.test W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread     exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2cddb20)
09-24 07:49:55.490 26661-26661/test.com.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.com.test, PID: 26661
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; regionStart=0; regionLength=500
    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:588)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1475)
    at test.com.test.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:39)
    at test.com.test.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:35)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you checking in Emulator or Device ?

Comment: in the emulator (however, it works for google.com and also other URLs I tried out).

Comment: I am having a similar issue excepts mine crashes on RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); Did anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You must be declare `RequestQueue queue;` before `onCreate()` and then initializing it in `onCreate()`